# How to delete last part of a string starting from the 1st non numeric character?

Tags: python, arcmap, field-calculator, vb, string

I'm looking for a Python or VB statement to remove the last part of a string, starting where the 1st non Numeric character appears, using the Field Calculator in ArcMap 10. Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Its not something I have much experience with but this sounds like a regular expression type problem. Have a look at [this](http://www.regexr.com/) website.

Comment: Despite being used in the Python Parser of the Field Calculator of ArcGIS for Desktop, this looks like a pure Python question that would be better researched/asked at StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a go at it. Use Python as the parser and check show Codeblock.

Enter this in the top Pre-Logic Script Code box:

```
def getints(field):

    integers = []
    for char in field:
        try:        
            value = int(char)
            integers.append(str(value))
        except ValueError:
            break

    return "".join(integers)
```

And put this in the bottom box:

```
getints(!YOURFIELD!)
```

Comment: @AntonioH Awesome!

Comment: How should I edit this python code if I wanted to "extract" all the consecutive numbers? For example:
Original String: "ADD. 420-"
Final String: "420".
Thanks!

Comment: @AntonioH You'll want to use the 'isdigit() ' method. I'm on my phone, but I'll try to show an example tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a field calculator method that incorporates [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile).  While ian's solution writes the new values to a text field, this is suited for writing to a numeric field.

```
import itertools

def convert(x):
  try:
    return int("".join(itertools.takewhile(str.isdigit, str(x))))
  except:
    pass
```

---

```
convert(!OriginalString!)
```

---

[image]