# Removing extra string from text column in Attribute Table to make numeric column from number part using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, attribute-table

I received a shapefile about invasive species. I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for desktop. In Attribute Table, there is column called "Infested_Area" and its got number mix with text, for instance "9100 sq feet". Since I can not run statistic on string I was wondering if it's possible to create a new filed and somehow get rid of the text portion of it and only have number!

Comment: If there is no decimal point, try this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118646/how-to-delete-last-part-of-a-string-starting-from-the-1st-non-numeric-character

Comment: This does not look like a duplicate of that particular question to me so I am going to provide an answer.

Comment: @PolyGeo I saw multiple examples when Qs like this were put on hold, reason OUT OF TOPIC.  What makes this one special?

Comment: @FelixIP There is a good argument for this one being off-topic and re-directing to [so], and I could easily have called it that way.  I didn't, perhaps because I was distracted by the duplicate being pointed at a question that seemed quite distinct.  Also, and it's only a personal rule of thumb, I tend to think that Field Calculator questions that do not need a Code Block tend to fall at the on-topic end.

Comment: @FelixIP Those "multiple examples" (with links) could be worth discussing in [Meta GIS SE](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry @PolyGeo I don't know what Meta GIS SE

Comment: @FelixIP  [Meta GIS Stack Exchange](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/) is the site where we discuss how the GIS Stack Exchange site works.  I know people have different views on where ArcGIS/ArcPy ends and Python ([so]) begins which would make it a worthwhile discussion.  It looks like we started to work on it but got side-tracked at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3796/when-are-field-calculator-scripting-questions-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [@PolyGeo solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164439/115)

[image]

but will handle different units and unitless entries

```
!TextField!.split(" ")[0]
```

Note you cannot run statistics on result, if units are different

Answer (score 1):

If your text field (mine is called TextField) always has the same string after the number like below then you can add a number field (mine is called IntegerField).

[image]

Then in the Field Calculator set the Parser to Python and use this as the expression to calculate your number field.

```
int( !TextField!.replace(" sq feet",""))
```

[image]

You should see the text stripped off in the output values for your number field.

[image]