# Removing portion of attribute string

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

I have done a bunch of internet research on this topic with no such luck. The closest I got to a solution is [Removing extra string from text column in Attribute Table to make numeric column from number part using ArcGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164389).

I have an attribute field "UniqueID" with information formatted as "NE_MH143". other information in this field start with "SE_", "NW_" and "SW_". I would like to reduce this information to remove the first three characters of the string.

Can this be done with ArcGIS field calculator?

[image: Attribute Table Screen Shot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To strip off the first 3 characters simply use the following in a field calculation:

```
!UniqueID![3:]
```

Comment: In the case of beginners - you need to change the parser to python for this calc.